# PDFkit doesn't display pictures in PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdfkit

Rails 2, PDFkit 0.5.0

Im generating a PDF from a View in Rails 2 with PDFkit and everything works fine. The only thing which doesn't work is displaying pictures in the pdf.

When I look at the View in the Browser, the picture is there but its missing in the PDF. There is only a placeholder existing in the PDF.

The image_tag is looking like this:

```
<%= image_tag('plus.gif') %>
```

I also tried to realize it with a css-file but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: PNG images doesnt work in some cases, use JPG

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because of the way that `wkhtmltopdf` works you need to specify the full path to any assets (JS, CSS, images etc), *including the domain name*.

This won't work:

```
<img src="/images/foo.png" />
```

This will:

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/foo.png" />
```

One workaround is to set an explicit asset host, even if it's the same server as your app is running on (see the [AssetTagHelper documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) for details). Another would be to specify the hostname in the `image_tag`.

Comment: Thx that works! <%= image_tag("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/foo.png")%>

Comment: That won't work if you want to render the view in your browser and also generate a PDF from it - depends on your requirements.

Comment: Also note if you are using full URL in your img tags you will need to be running a multi-{thread, process} server, such as unicorn, in development as it will need to process two requests at once.

Comment: RAILS_ROOT has been deprecated since Rails 3.0. What should I do instead?

Comment: @fatuhoku Rails.root serves the same purpose as far as I know.

Comment: <%= image_tag(image_url("kunzig-logo.png", host: "http://localhost:3000/"), style: "width: 100%;") %>   This made it so I can preview in dev.  Just be sure to change the host option after lol

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the full path each time, you can add a base tag to the head section.

```
<base href="http://mydomain.com" target="_blank" />
```