# pdfkit not rendering images and css to the pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdfkit

I have generated a pdf using pdfkit but it is neither rendering images nor the css file. I don't know why this is happening. Any help will be appreciable.

Layout : (report.html.erb)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'merchant_report', rel: 'stylesheet'%>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Action : (report.pdf.erb)

```
<div class="checkin_data">
  <h4 style="text-align: center;">No. of Customers Vs. Date</h4>
  <div>No. of Checkins during this period on a day wise basis</div>
  <% image_name = Time.now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y").to_s + '_' + $merchant.id.to_s + '_check_in_visit_history_image.png' %>
  <!-- <img src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/system/report/#{image_name}"/> -->
  <%= image_tag("/assets/images/report/#{image_name}")%>
  <br>
  <h4 style="text-align: center;">No. of Customers Vs. No. of Visits</h4>
  <div>No. of Visits per Customer during this period</div>
  <canvas height="400" width="600" id="customer_visit"></canvas>
  <br>
</div>
```

Controller : (merchant_report_controller)

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        html = render_to_string(:layout => "report.html.erb" , :action => "report.pdf.erb")
         kit = PDFKit.new(html)
         kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/public/system/stylesheets/merchant_report.css"
         send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "some_name.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')
         return
      end
    end
```

pdfkit.rb

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
  config.default_options = {
    :page_size => 'Legal',
    :print_media_type => true,
    :disable_javascript => true
  }
  # Use only if your external hostname is unavailable on the server.
  config.root_url = "http://localhost:3000"
  config.verbose = false
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you're looking for the stylesheet in the correct place? They're usually stored in `app/assets/stylesheets`

Comment: I had tried that also but didn't get styling. Previously i tried "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/stylesheets/merchant_report.css". In both the case i didn't get pdf.

Comment: Try changing the disposition to `attachment` and see if you get styles by downloading it.

Comment: It didn't work. I have sorted styling by putting all the css on a page but how can i embed image to pdf?

Comment: Try doing the same thing with the image, add the public path to it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6110131/338536